# How to use google.maps within an asmx web service

Tags: maps, asmx

I need to calculate distances for some logic within a web service and assume google.maps API is appropriate.  Everything I've seen is Jscript and requires a reference to the script in html tags `<script>`, which does not apply here.  A .dll would make things obvious to me, but that does not seem to be available...

How do you access google.maps within a c# .asmx??

Answer (score 1):

You will have to do the same thing that would be done by the JavaScript code you're seeing as examples. You'll want to use the `WebClient` class or maybe the `WebRequest` class to do the network I/O, but you've got to send and receive HTTP messages.

"Add Service Reference" won't work, of course.

Note that this problem is not specific to ASMX web services. You would have the exact same issue in a console program or Winforms application.